# MUI slider not draggable more than one step at a time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mapbox

So I have a mui slider on my map that changes the year of display data for a specific Layer. However my Mui slider is not "draggable" it only lets me move one step at a time then stops and I have to let go of the slider and then redrag it. Clicking around on it works fine. When setYear changes it runs a function in usememo that changes the layer. I suspect this might be the problem but have can I avoid it?

```
const handleTimeChange = (event, newValue) => {
    if (newValue !== year) {
      setYear(newValue);
    }
  };
<Slider
        getAriaLabel={() => "Date range"}
        value={year}
        onChange={handleTimeChange}
        valueLabelDisplay="auto"
        sx={{ width: "200px", ml: "20px" }}
        max={2020}
        min={min}
        align="center"
      />
```

Comment: i can't reproduce the error, here it seems to work fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-sound-zdoz6r?file=/src/App.js.
Try to provide more information for the context of your case scenario.

Comment: @FedericoRoma, Could you please explain why it happens for me here then? Do I need to use some type of hook or something? https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-bardeen-bp26tb?file=/index.js

Comment: Since you are defining another component that way, it's like it has another state. You can fix it moving the state variables and the handleChange function inside InnComeSlider component, or remove the InnComeSlider and render the Box and slider directly in App. Or you could try to pass those values as props to InnComeSlider component.